# How can i do a minus b whole square in java

Tags: java, android, math

I have to implement a formula in my application which uses this equation

lets suppose i have (1 - (2.0/3.0)) raised to 2.

```
    double w, double h

    (Math.pow((1 - (w / h)), 2))  //which obviously gave me wrong answer
```

So i had to implement the equation in the following ways..i was wondering whether there was an easier way to do this.

Is there a better way to do this than doing it this way?

```
Math.pow(a,2) - 2 * (a * b) + Math.pow(b,2)
```

Comment: It's giving you a wrong answer, because `2/3` is integer division and gives `0`

Comment: As @QBrute mentioned, you're trying to do this with the wrong numeric type.  You'll have to type out `2.0` (or `2.0f` if you need less precision from `Float`) to get the benefits of floating point arithmetic.

Comment: sorry my bad i have edited my question. :)

Comment: Why do you think this gave you the wrong answer?  What answer did it give you?

Comment: @DavidWallace you are correct issue was somewhere else. upvoting your answer thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be a straightforward and computationally efficient way to do this:

```
double result = 1 - w/h;
result *= result;
```

It's likely to be faster to raise in the second power by a single multiplication than calling `Math.pow` and it's arguably simpler to type.

Similarly for your second formula :

```
double result2 = a*a - 2*a*b + b*b;
```